# Randomly accessing a file

Tags: c++

I am looking for some help with my program for accessing my file randomly. I want the user to enter the record they would like to access in my File and have it displayed to them. I have found some code on some websites that run it close to how I want it but I don't really understand. Here is all my code for the project. `RandomReadProcess()` was what my instructor emailed me as an example and `RandomReadGiveMeFileLocation()` is what I am working on right now. `

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CFile
{

            public:
        CFile(){}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Opening and Closing Files

        void OpenTheFileWrite()
        {
            WRITE.open("File20.txt",ios::app);
        }
        void CloseTheFileWrite()
        {
            WRITE.close();
        }
        void OpenTheFileRead()
        {
            READ.open("File20.txt");
        }
        void CloseTheFileRead()
        {
            READ.close();
        }`enter code here`
        void OpenTheFileWriteANewOne()
        {
            WRITE.open("File21.txt");
        }
        void CloseTheFileWriteANewOne()
        {
            WRITE.close();
        }
        void OpenForRandomAccess()
        {
            ReadWrite.open("File21.txt",ios::in | ios::out );
        }
        void CloseForRandomAccess()
        {
            ReadWrite.close();
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Spacing for the data in file20.txt



                void FormatDataForWriting()
        {
            int k;
            // Clean the Buffer
            for ( k = 0; k < 47; k++ )
            {
                Data[k] = 32;// ascii code for space 
            }
            Data[46] = '\0';

            for ( k = 0; k < strlen(FirstName); k++ )
            {
                Data[k] = FirstName[k];
            }
            for ( k = 0; k < strlen(LastName); k++ )
            {
                Data[k+15] = LastName[k];
            }
            for ( k = 0; k < strlen(SSN); k++ )
            {
                Data[k+35] = SSN[k];
            }
        }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Writes the data to File20.txt



                void WriteRecords()
        {
            int k,HowMany;

            cout << "\n\t\tInput how many records : ";
            cin >> HowMany;

            for ( k = 0; k < HowMany; k++ )
            {
                cout << "\n\t\tFirstName : ";
                cin >> FirstName;
                cout << "\t\tLastName  : ";
                cin >> LastName;
                cout << "\t\tSSN       : ";
                cin >> SSN;
                FormatDataForWriting();
                WRITE << Data;
            }
        }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



                void ReadRecords()
        {
            string MeUp,HolderOne;
            int k,m;

            OpenTheFileRead();  /////////opens File20.txt       
            getline(READ,MeUp); /////////Reads all of File20.txt
            CloseTheFileRead(); /////////closes File20.txt

            OpenTheFileWriteANewOne();  //////Opens File21.txt

            for ( k = 0; k < MeUp.length(); k++ )     /////
            { 
                if ( MeUp.length() % 46 == 0 )        ////     Oragnizes the input of the file.
                {
                    HolderOne = MeUp.substr(k,46);    ////     Everything goes down.
                    HolderOne += 13;                  ////  
                    HolderOne += 10;                  ////  
                    WRITE << HolderOne;              /////
                }
                k = k + 45;
            }
            CloseTheFileWriteANewOne();  //////Closes File21.txt
        }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                 void RandomReadProcess()
        {
            char Buffer[255];
            int k,HowManyRecords;


            OpenForRandomAccess();
            ReadWrite.seekg(0,ios::end);
            k = ReadWrite.tellg();
            HowManyRecords = k / 47;
            for (k = 0; k < HowManyRecords; k++)
            {
                ReadWrite.seekg(k*48,ios::beg);
                ReadWrite.read(Buffer,47);
                Buffer[46] = '\0';
            //  cout << "\n\t\tThe record read = " << Buffer;
            }
            CloseForRandomAccess();

        }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


               void RandomReadGiveMeFileLocation()
        {
            int k,m,RecordNumber;

            OpenForRandomAccess();
            RandomReadProcess();


                cout << "\n\t\t\tGive me Record # : ";
                cin  >> RecordNumber;

                ReadWrite.seekg(RecordNumber*sizeof(ReadWrite),ios::beg);
                ReadWrite.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ReadWrite),sizeof(ReadWrite));

                cout << "\n\t\t\tFirstName: ";
                cout << ReadWrite.Data << endl;
                cout << "\n\t\t\tLastName: ";
        //      cout << ReadWrite. << endl;
                cout << "\n\t\t\tSSN: ";
        //      cout << ReadWrite.SSN << endl;


            CloseForRandomAccess();

        }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            private:
        char FirstName[16];
        char LastName[21];
        char SSN[10];
        char Data[48];
        ofstream WRITE;
        ifstream READ;
        fstream ReadWrite;

};
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Help" is too generic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Basically its just how do I randomly get any info from a file. Being like in my case a record and having that record displayed.

Comment: You can use binary files. It's also possible to overload operator [] for access to i'th string and j'th field (if strings content has some structure).

Comment: You have taken your instructor's example and made *many changes at once*, including *changes to things you didn't understand*. Try understanding your instructor's code first, then changing one thing at a time, testing at every step.

Comment: Hints: Most likely, you won't need any casts. If you can, buy a good book. If not, copy one. In any case, read documentation. Start with an example which you understand, play around, make small modifications (Beta is right) until it does what you wanted.

Comment: Oh, and since you are trying to learn C++: Do not use number literals except for defining consts; avoid working on raw data like char * but use standard library types like string. Build your own classes (`Record` calls out to me "make me  class!")-- But if you want to program on the concrete level demonstrated here (char *, record oriented disk access) you may be better off with C! It's generally more straightforward and there may be less opportunity for error.